# Sonata Admin Bundle grant permissions to a custom admin role

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using the "role" security handler and want to create a new role "ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN" and grant all permissions to it, like:

```
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN: [MASTER]
```

the only way I could grant my user all permissions was to give it in security.yml:

```
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN:
   - ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
```

but I don't want to include ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN in my role, as I will maybe want to add some restrictions in the future

I tried to use acl

```
handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
```

but getting:
`Argument 2 passed to Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\AclSecurityHandler::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\MutableAclProviderInterface`

role handler is enough for me and I don't need acl

How can I create a role and grant permissions to it? I've read the documentation but still don't understand

**Edit:** I understand now: for every entity I need to set permissions via roles in security.yml with ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_[service name]_[permission]
my service name is:  sonata.admin.widget
here the solution:

```
        ROLE_SONATA_WIDGET_ADMIN:
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_LIST
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_VIEW
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_CREATE
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_EDIT
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_DELETE
      - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_WIDGET_EXPORT

    ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN:
      - ROLE_SONATA_WIDGET_ADMIN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check point 23.3 in the [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html). You can add roles in the **security.yml**. If you are using the role handler it works like this.

```
security:
    ...
    role_hierarchy:
        # for convenience, I decided to gather Sonata roles here
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_READER:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_VIEW
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_EDITOR:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_CREATE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EDIT
        ROLE_SONATA_FOO_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_DELETE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_EXPORT
        # those are the roles I will use (less verbose)
        ROLE_STAFF:             [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_READER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_EDITOR, ROLE_SONATA_FOO_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```